# UMP test with two distributions derivation

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

> Suppose X has distribution in $\mathcal{P}=\{B(10, \frac{1}{2}), P(1)\}$ (Binomial and Poisson respectively). Let $H_0 := X \stackrel{D}{=} B(10, \frac{1}{2})$ and $H_1 := X \stackrel{D}{=}P(1)$. Derive an UMP test for $H_0$ with $\alpha = 0.1$

There is also a hint to use tables of Poisson or Binomial distribution.

I know $\alpha$ = $\mathbb{P}_0(f_1(x) > cf_0(x)) + \gamma \mathbb{P}_0(f_1(x)=cf_0(x)$.

I calculated $f_1(x) > c f_0(x)$ as
$$
\frac{1}{e x!} > c \frac{10!}{(10-x)!x!}2^{-10} \\
\frac{2^{10}}{e} > c 10^{\underline{x}} \\
\frac{2^{10}}{e 10^{\underline{x}}} > c 
$$

When I plug that in
$$
\alpha = \mathbb{P}_0(f_1(x) > cf_0(x)) + \gamma \mathbb{P}_0(f_1(x)=cf_0(x)  = \\
=  \mathbb{P}_0(\frac{2^{10}}{e 10^{\underline{x}}} > c) + \gamma \mathbb{P}_0(\frac{2^{10}}{e 10^{\underline{x}}} = c)
$$
Here I got stuck. I know that I need to assume the $H_0$ is true so $X \stackrel{D}{=} B(10, \frac{1}{2})$ but I have $10^{\underline{X}}$ here. Surely I must be missing something. I usually used CLT here but I have no idea how to do it here. Thank you for any insights.

Comment: $\{B(10, \frac{1}{2}, P(1)\}$ at the beginning is missing a bracket, presumably $\{B(10, \frac{1}{2}), P(1)\}$, but what does $P(1)$ represent?

Comment: Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use the Neyman–Pearson lemma

It should be obvious that if $x \gt 10$ then $\mathbb P(X=x \mid H_0)=0$ and $\mathbb P(X=x \mid H_1)>0$, so the likelihood ratio is then zero

For $0 \le x \le 10$, the likelihood ratio is $\dfrac{\frac{10!}{(10-x)!x!}2^{-10} }{e^{-1}\frac{1^x}{x!}} = \dfrac{10!2^{-10}e}{(10-x)!}$, which is an increasing function of $x$.

So for a UMP test, you are going to reject $H_0$ when $X$ is strictly greater than $10$ or strictly smaller than some value $k$ when $\mathbb P(k \le X=x \le 10 \mid H_0)$ is at least  $1-\alpha=0.9$, where $k$ is the largest possible value subject to that constraint.  I suspect $k=3$; depending on what you have been taught, you might or might not want to do something special when $X=3$

Comment: Thank you very much. By "something special" you probably mean for $S = \{0, 1, 2\}$ we will have $\mathbb{P}(X \in S) < \alpha$ and if we add another point $k = 3$ we would get $\mathbb{P}(X \in S) > \alpha$ - that means we have to "randomise" the test and add $k=3$ with some probability such that $\mathbb{P}(X \in \{0,1,2,3\}) = \alpha$, right?

Comment: If I may - why the fact that "likelihood function is increasing" plays an important role here? Does that allow us to pick $k$s in a monotone way(starting from 0 and going "up" all way to 10) when building the critical set(I don't know if that is correct english term)?

Comment: So, my answer would be that UMP test looks as follows: $\phi(x) = 1$ when $x > 10$ or $x < 3$; $\phi(x) = 0.38$ when $x = 3$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ otherwise. Does that look correct? I got the $0.38$ using tables - $S = \{0,1,2\}$ had probability $0.055$ and $S = \{0,1,2, 3\}$ had something above $\alpha = 0.1$ so solving $0.055 + p\cdot \mathbb{P}_0(X = 3) = \alpha$ left me with $p = 0.38$.

Comment: Yes - $0.38666\ldots$ would be even better